# MediaRecorder getting a video output in android without writting to disk

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder

After looking at the documentation for MediaRecorder, and examples for MediaRecorder using Camera2, I can't seem to find anywhere how not to write the video to disk, and simply getting the output directly in my program.

I need to upload the video directly to a server, and having to save it to disk would be a needless overhead.

Comment: Do you need to upload a finished file to the server, or are you streaming it to a server? Do you need .mp4 format, or is H.264 okay? IIRC the MediaRecorder MP4 file writer likes to seek back to the start of the file and write a header when the file is complete, which is why it insists on writing to a file.

Comment: H.264 would be okay, if it saves me the overhead of writing to disk, reading from disk and only then sending to server